# PyDev no Eclipse: Unable to get project for the run

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

Eu estou com um problema relacionado a configuração do interpretador do PyDev no  eclipse, toda vez que eu tento dar o Run, aparece o seguinte erro:

> "Unable to get project for the run"

Alguém já teve esse erro usando o eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Nas configurações do compilador/interpretador, você deve passar o caminho do interpretador python. o PyDev não ver completamente configurado.

Segue o modelo da imagem abaixo e o link do **[Manual](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html)**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então, eu já havia feito essa configuração, seguindo as instruções desse link aqui: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html
mas mesmo assim eu não consegui.
Resolvi desinstalar e excluir todos os arquivos do eclipse do meu computador e reinstalá-lo. Funcionou :)
Mas muito obrigada pela atenção.